# Route Output to Input/Skype Upload Greeter Audio File

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, skype, vlc, alsa

I need to record a greeting message in Skype, but I already have a .flac but I don't think you can do this so I thought maybe there is a way to pipe vlc's output to skype's input. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 1):

Skype supports an easy-to-set up voicemail system. One convenient benefit of setting up Skype Voicemail is that your audio messages — both your greeting and the incoming messages people leave you — are not stored on your computer but instead are stored remotely on Skype's central servers. As a result, you don't have to worry about missing calls when you turn off your computer.

Before you can use Skype Voicemail, you have to start your setup and record the Voicemail greeting that your callers will hear:

see [tutorial here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-skype-voicemail.html)